# "Class not found" Adding custom DQL function in Symfony 3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I'm attempting to register a set of third-party DQL functions in a Symfony 3 app. I've followed [Symfony's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) and have a `config.yml` with (among other fields):

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                to_tsquery: OpsWay\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ToTsquery
                to_tsvector: OpsWay\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\ToTsvector
                ts_match_op: OpsWay\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsMatch
```

However, when I run my code that calls these functions in the DQL, I get an error of `Class '\OpsWay\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\TsMatch' not found`. I've guaranteed that there are no misspellings and that the files are installed via Composer. I can even successfully Cmd+Click in PHPStorm to get to the class from the `config.yml`. Is there something that I'm missing to get these functions registered?

Comment: Update: For whatever reason, if I copied the contents of these files into my AppBundle and changed the namespace, it worked. Really strange, and not ideal, but it's served as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace starts with **Opsway** but not **OpsWay**.

> Opsway\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions